# join a net.socket connection to a socket.io room

Tags: node.js, io, socket.io

I have two servers ( server A and server B ).
Server B triggers an action that should create an instance of socket in Server A to generate a room.

My current problem is we're using 'net' socket which is not viable to use the Room functionality that's only in socket.io. How to add a netSocket connection to a socket.io rooms..?

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
   socket.on('join_room', function(){
     //socket.join('room_created_from_net_socket');
   })
})

var server = net.createServer(function (conn) {
    conn.id = conn.remoteAddress + ":" + conn.remotePort
    // create a room here
})
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you remove the net socket server from the middle and make life easier..? :p

Comment: If you mean a Net socket from the .net-Framework it should be possible to use nodes tcp or udp sockets to handle the communication between Server A and Server B

Comment: we cant just simply remove it because there will be a lot of scanner, and each scanner needs to have its own node server(server B). Server A becomes the middle-ware or bridge to multiple clients